# Accidently Deleted /etc/nginx, anyway to regenerate our custom nginx.conf?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

I was using nano to edit nginx.conf to turn Google Pagespeed off and apparently it shredded the nginx.conf file and the entire /etc/nginx directory. The entire folder is gone.

Our /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file had a ton of customization and URL rewriting which we edited over several years, so I'm trying to somehow restore the nginx.conf file. We never made a backup, unfortunately. Live and learn!

In trying to Google if I can restore nginx.conf, I've heard rumblings it's possible to regenerate the file from the server's memory. My server should still be actively using it since I haven't restarted nginx, right? Or would it only restore a fresh copy with none of our customization?

I have very limited experience using SSH and Linux -- I'm more of a Wordpress and PHP guy. Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if this info is helpful but we're running Debian 8.1. Thank you!

Comment: I run several servers with Linux and Nginx in a VPS, it's worth nothing that, if you have this kind of servers it's a good idea to always have a snapshot of your HD, so you can recovery something later, I have custom Nginx configs that I always keep a copy offline if something goes messy I can quickly recover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
nginx -T
```

to see the running config. Note: This only works with version 1.9.2 and above

To check your version use:

```
nginx -v
```

If your version is below 1.9.2 you can look at the following post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I have version 1.8.0. I'll look into that post.